# What are the differences between the NA and EU versions of Tera?

Tags: tera

Tera has gone free to play. There are two publishers for the English version - one for EU, one for NA. Luckily, the Internet has no oceans, so ignoring ping, a player is free to choose the version they prefer. What are the differences between the two, if any?

Comment: I really don't see how creating a list of minor differences is contructive.  Most of any of the differences likely has to due with the payment of services and expectation of publisher thereof to provide those services.

Comment: @Ramhound Quality of implementation is heavily dependent on the publisher - from stability through microtransaction costs to customer service quality. Without having the list it's not possible to determine whether the differences are minor or not. IMO having the list is constructive, as long as it's about having an objective list and not about straight out asking people to debate which is better. You could argue that getting the list is hard (true, probably the reason there's no answer yet), but then there's no rule against hard questions.

Comment: Honestly...I view this as a polling question if you must know.

Comment: I haven't played EU Tera much, but I noticed that the trade broker was... empty. No bank expansions or character slots in sight. If you're planning to play F2P, definitely go for NA Tera.